# Loading image isnt displaying until after the page has loaded.

Tags: java, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am a newbie to the world of javascript/jquery.

I am trying to show a loading image until my page has finished loading. I dont know where I am going wrong. I have read many posts regarding this already but my image and script are both not working. Please see my markup below. I have tried using response.write(html string) and response.flush to sort this out and it works but i then have a major issue at response.redirect with headers already sent as flush causes html buffer to flush. I have used the same code as below in the script tag except didnt have window.load bit in there. This is due to my putting my response.write and flush in page event init & pre-render.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - InfoCentre MI TEST VERSION</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">        
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load = function () {
            var elem = document.getElementById("dvLoading");
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dvLoading" style="text-align:right;">
        <img id="imgLoading" src="Images/loading4.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="LoadingImage" />
    </div>
    <form runat="server">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : hide image after window load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $("#dvLoading").hide();
            });
    </script>
```

**NOTE** - make sure that you have added jquery library before above script. If not then add below line before `<script>` tag

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function () {
          $("#dvLoading").hide();
      });
 </script>
```

For more information on load event - [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: I dont have css. I have just inherited this project from a guy who has left and he has no cms. Now the only problem is showing the image while page is loading. Sure enough i can clear the image using the code above but i cant display it without css in place. Is there anyway i can do this without css please.

Comment: what css are you talking about? Can you post the css code and how does it affecting your code? as per Question you want to hide image after page load right?

Comment: Not only do i want to hide it on load. I also want to display one while page is loading. For this all tutorials on internet suggest putting a div straight after body tag and then adding the bits to it via css. When i do this, all my other elements on the page disappear. its annoying.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle link with your problem statement, so that i can help you better.